# Как соединить выражение IF и INSERT INTO в postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Хочу чтобы данные в столбец "korzina" заносились только если соблюдается условие user_id=(определенное число), но при попытке выполнить код ниже выходит ошибка: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "INTO")

```
SELECT user_id, korzina, IF(user_id=890, INSERT INTO bot_users('korzina') VALUES ('balbes'), korzina) FROM bot_users;
```

Что нужно изменить в коде чтобы данные добавлялись в колонку напротив другой колонки с определенным значением

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: не вижу ничего непонятного в этом вопросе, используемый код предоставлен, что нужно получить описано, ошибка показана, дак в чем проблема?

Comment: *"Хочу чтобы данные в столбец "korzina" заносились только если соблюдается условие user_id=(определенное число)"* --- делайте это в коде бэкенда... сейчас вы просто нарушаете синтаксис SQL. Это в принципе с логической точки некорректно вызывать Insert в операции выборки....

Comment: а что значит *"данные добавлялись в колонку напротив другой колонки"* ?

Comment: Некорректно выразился, я имею ввиду что я получаю айди покупателя и когда он добавляет что-то в корзину я добавляю это в столбик корзина который находится в одной строке с данным айди,  и я не знаю как это реализовать, буду крайне благодарен если вы подскажете

Comment: и кстати, я все делаю с помощью psycopg2 Python, просто сначала пробую команду в самом sql а уже потом переношу в код

Comment: *не вижу ничего непонятного в этом вопросе, используемый код предоставлен, что нужно получить описано, ошибка показана, дак в чем проблема?* Прочитайте ссылку ещё раз, особенно пункты 5 и 3. То, что Вы не видите, что ещё нужно, следствие незнания SQL. Но поверьте, если что-то просят дополнительно, то оно нужно.